# how to make layout of a video view underneath a scrollable text view and underneath a horizontal scroll view of images?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to make an app which loads the data from cloud and plays a video on the top, next followed by the scrollable TextView about the video and also i would like to add screen-shots(images) of the video at bottom of the screen in horizontal scroll view. its means three views one after the other in a layout..please help me.!
For Example in a youtube app - when a video is playing we can scroll the TextView below the video.

thanks.

Comment: I don't see a specific question. Please read over [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: where is the image? and did you google your question? its all about nesting your views- i'd suggest vertical orientation linearlayout with vertical scrollayout with a textview as child view then a horizontal scrollview.. since the parent is a linearlayout with orientation vertical it will position the views to your preferred interest..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use a LinearLayout so you can specify weight to each item. 
Read the documentation here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html

```
____________________________ 
|                          | ( weight is 2, which mean it will be twice as big as "1")
|                          |
|                          |
|     place video here     |
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
|                          |
____________________________
|                          | (weight is 1)
|      scrollview here     |
|                          |
____________________________
|                          | (weight is 1)
|     thumbnails here      |
|                          |
____________________________
```